# Sale ends October 10

Tags: prepositions

I saw the following sentence:

> Sale ends October 10.

To me, "Sale ends **on** October 10" would sound a lot better.

Which one is correct?

Comment: No doubt you saw this abomination in one of the colonies. The correct way is and always will be; 10th October.

Comment: JoeDark's lighthearted comment aside, I see nothing wrong with it, particularly if you saw this in a circular or on a sign. Brevity is often valued over formality in such contexts.

Comment: @J.R. Is not that more the *spoken* form instead of the grammatically correct one?

Comment: @Begueradj - Who said that an advertisement needs to be (or should be) "grammatically correct"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single, grammatically correct format for announcing when a sale ends.

The format of the date can be provided in several forms, and the date might include or omit a time, a day of the week, or the year. An article, adjective, or pronoun might be included; a preposition may be included or omitted. The word "sale" might be omitted, or replaced with another word. None of these variations should be cause for concern; these are all normal ways to convey information, particularly in brief forms of communication such as headlines and advertisements.

I just did a little online browsing, and found all of these formats:

> - Sale ends Oct 3
> - Ends Oct 14
> - Sale ends October 13, 2014
> - Store-wide sale ends Saturday, October 25, 2014
> - Offer ends 11:59PM CST 10/07/2012
> - Sale ends 12PM Friday 14th March 2014 (AEDT)

None of these would bother me, either:

> - This deal ends on Sunday, October 11th
> - Offer expires November 1st
> - Now thru December 31, 2015

I don't think those ads would "sound a lot better" with the *on* included. (Then again, I've been seeing ads like this for decades, so I'm accustomed to it.)

[image]